# Literature for ODE undergrad class

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, education

I am teaching a undergrad ODE class. I am looking for some good (introductory) articles with applications of ODE's. In particular I would like some motivations for some special functions (Legendre, Bessel, Hermite, Chebyshev, etc). Unfortunately the book we are using (Boyce-DiPrima) doesn't motivate them.

I found some recent applications of spherical harmonics to computer graphics which seem very interesting. However, I think the level is quite high for my class.

Thanks,

Comment: There is a [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64216/mathematics-educators) for a Mathematics Educators' SE site in commit state right now.

Comment: In my experience, students do "get" things (even very complex things) given sufficient interest. Finding the interesting applications is the hard part...

Answer (score 1):

See the web page [Student Projects in Differential Equations](http://msemac.redwoods.edu/~darnold/math55/DEproj/index.php) maintained by David Arnold at **College of the Redwoods**. I remember seeing this back in the late 1990s when I taught an ODEs course for a few years, and I was quite surprised just now to find that they're still available and still on-going when I did a quick search for it.